# How to bulk unit test collections of objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

When I'm doing unit testing for code that I don't trust very much, I'll commonly use this pattern:

1. Think up many (perhaps dozens) of expectations I have for the output of my function (I think of these as "theories" about how the code works).
2. Spin up many thousands of objects.
3. Run each object through the dozens of assertions I've coded up reflecting my expectations of how the code works.

In Ruby's Test::Unit (to which I am new), I've been doing something like this:

```
class TestFooBarrer < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @lots_of_objects_to_be_tested = FooBarrer.bar_lots_of_foos
  end

  def assert_foo_has_been_barred(foo)
    assert_kind_of Bar, foo
  end

  def assert_foo_has_baz_method(foo)
    assert_respond_to foo, :baz
  end

  #Many more assertions along those lines go here.

  def test_all_theories
    @lots_of_objects_to_be_tested.each do |foo|
      assert_foo_has_been_barred(foo)
      assert_foo_has_baz_method(foo)
      # etc.
      #
    end
  end
end
```

This obviously gets a bit unwieldy when the number of theories I'm testing is in the dozens, and involves what looks to me like a lot of needless repetition. I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
class FooTheories
  def self.assert_all_theories(foo)
    # ???
  end

  def assert_foo_has_been_barred(foo)
    assert_kind_of Bar, foo
  end

  def assert_foo_has_baz_method(foo)
    assert_respond_to foo, :baz
  end

  #Many more assertions along those lines go here.
end


class TestFooBarrer < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @lots_of_objects_to_be_tested = FooBarrer.bar_lots_of_foos
  end

  def test_all_theories
    @lots_of_objects_to_be_tested.each do |foo|
      FooTheories.assert_all_theories(foo)
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to write a bunch of assertions in one place and then call them over and over again on a large quantity of objects.

Is there any support for something like that in Ruby? I'm not tied to Test::Unit particularly. Any of the testing frameworks is fine.

Comment: Oh, please don't use "theories", even in quotes :(

Comment: "Hypotheses" would be more to the point, but it's hard to type :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is generate tests on the fly. Add a method in your test_helper:

```
def test(obj, &block)
  define_method("test_#{ obj.to_s }", &block)
end
```

And then you can make your test suite like the following

```
class TestObjects < Test::Unit::TestCase

  @objects_to_test = [...]

  @objects_to_test.each do |obj|
    test obj do

      assert obj.is_a?(Foo), 'not a foo'

      # all assertions here

    end
  end

end
```

And then if it fails, you'll get to know which object failed because the name of the test is the string representation of the object. Ex message:

```
1) Failure:
test_#<Bar:0x000001009ee930>(TestObjects):
not a foo
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I figured there was some kind of meta-programming solution.